# email notifications from SQL Server job

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-mail, sql-server-job

We want to set a profile in Database Mail on SQL Server 2008 R2 for all the developers in our team to receive notifications once an overnight job has completed.

Unfortunately, in the Notifications properties in the job it only allows us to select one of the Operators (*Data Management Developers*) and the problem with using the Operator is that there is a 100 nvarchar limit on how many characters (and therefore how many email addresses) can be added.

How can we select the new profile for notifications? Do we have to delete the Operator?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to administering your email subsystem you can create dedicated email account for Operator and configure email forwarding from it to all recipients you need. This simplifies database mail administering as well as email subsystem administering.